# Who prepared everything to make the Dragon Emperor's return easy, and why?

Tags: the-mummy-tomb-of-dragon-emperor

In [The Mummy: Tomb of the Dragon Emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mummy:_Tomb_of_the_Dragon_Emperor) it looked like the witch's spell turned EVERYONE at Dragon Emperor's court into a statue.

Yet, after she cast it:

- Someone swapped out the Emperor's mummy from coffin to the chariot
- An underground tomb was constructed
- **the tomb had giant sliding ramps/trapdoor combinations which could be lowered to let his terracota army to march out**.
- etc...

If everyone was *terracotaed* by the spell, **who and why made all the preparations** that only made sense if it was known that the Emperor would return as a Mummy later on and would be able to reanimate his army?

Comment: Is it not possible that it was designed that way for ease of putting them there to begin with?

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14557/who-hid-the-dragon-emperor-and-his-army-after-they-were-cursed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer (at least according to the film's [draft script](http://pdfscripts.weebly.com/uploads/9/1/6/8/916864/the_mummy_iii.pdf)) is that the Emperor was placed into the tomb **by his loyal eunuchs** and that **his army was left inside the Palace**. It's hardly a stretch to imagine that what we're viewing as "ramps" are in fact the Palace steps, with a few extra bits added by the eunuchs for easy access:

> **NARRATOR (V.O.)** *The Eunuchs buried the Emperor in a crypt below the courtyard. As for his warriors, the palace became their tomb.*
>
> PUSH into his lifeless eyes.
>
> **NARRATOR (V.O.)** *The people believed that if the Emperor awoke, he would raise his army and finish his crusade to enslave the world.*

The people who lived in his Empire were evidently anticipating that he would continue his quest if/when he recovered, hence why they buried him *in situ*.

Answer (score 2):

After reading this very poorly written [wiki](http://mummy.wikia.com/wiki/The_Mummy:_Tomb_of_the_Dragon_Emperor) to refresh my memory, it appears that no one preemptively planned for the catacombs and tomb for the emperor and his army. The emperor was searching for a way to live forever, and the sorceress he found instead cursed him because she was in love with the emperors friend, but all were forbidden to touch her. The emperor ordered her to be his queen or he would kill his friend/her lover. she refused however and the emperor stabs her, but that triggers the curse she put on him (instead of eternal life) and turned him and his army into terracotta. she then flees wounded and we arrive in the the present(1940's)

It appears that only the emperor and his army where cursed, so the regular citizens would be left with 1000s of these statues, and a dead emperor. It seems they simply dug caverns and placed the emperor and his army in them.

I would hazard that the survivors would see everyone as cursed, and want to bury/hide them away, but at the same time not destroy them for fear of angering/affecting the curse.

as to the tombs design for the terracotta army to march out, we don't have much to go on, as historically [the tombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terracotta_Army) did not have this feature.

Edit- and as @dave Johnson states, the ramps may have also been added by the constructors for ease in moving the statue'd army down there.

Otherwise it appears its a convenience built into the movie with no explanation.

Comment: This doesn't address that this was explicitly designed to easily march out the Terracota army